# Selecting all rows from Informix table containing some null columns

Tags: sql, perl, informix

I am using Perl DBD::ODBC to connect to an Informix database which I was previously blind to the schema of. I have successfully discovered the schema via querying tabname and colname tables. I am now iterating over each of those tables extracting everything in them to load into another model. What I am finding is that null columns bail out of the select query. E.g. if a table looked like this, with an optionally null `lastseen` column (of whatever data type):

```
ID    username    lastseen
--    --------    --------
1     joe         1234567890
2     bob         1098765432
3     mary        
4     jane        1246803579
```

then `select * from mytable` (or specifying all column names indiidually) stops at the **mary** row.

I do have this working by using NVL as follows:

```
select nvl(id, ''), nvl(username, ''), nvl(lastseen, '') from mytable
```

And that's *okay*, but **my question is: Is there a simpler Informix syntax to allow nulls to come into my result set**, something as simple as `NULLS OK` or something that I am missing? Alternatively, some database handle option to allow the same?

Here is an example of my Perl with the nvl() hack, in case it's relevant:

```
my %tables = (
    users => [
        qw(id username lastseen)
    ]
);

foreach my $tbl (sort keys %tables) {
    my $sql = 'select ' . join(',', map { "nvl($_, '')" } @{$tables{$tbl}}) . " from $tbl";
    # sql like: select nvl(a, ''), nvl(b, ''), ...
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute;
    while(defined(my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref)) {
        # do ETL stuff with $row
    }
}
```

Comment: That really shouldn't be necessary. Certainly DBD::Informix handles NULL values properly - is there a good reason you can't use that driver rather than the ODBC one?

Comment: Semi-good, just that I'm in a very large and paranoid enterprise environment and it's actually a giant pain to get new modules installed, probably not worth the effort for this limited application since I do have a workaround. We've got other solutions similarly using ODBC to abstract the database layer so I'd certainly be interested in learning its limitations and quirks, if that is indeed the culprit (and I'm very willing to believe it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a balked attempt at installing DBD::Informix I came back around to this and found that for some reason enabling `LongTruncOk` on the database handle did allow all rows including those with null columns to be selected. I don't imagine this is the root of the issue but it worked here.

However, this solution seems to have collided with an unrelated tweak to locales to support non-ascii characters. I added `DB_LOCALE=en_us.utf8` and `CLIENT_LOCALE=en_us.utf8` to my connection string to prevent selects from similarly breaking when encountering non-ascii characters (i.e., in a result set of say 500 where the 300th row had a non-ascii character the trailing 200 rows would not be returned). With locales set this way as well as `LongTruncOk` enabled on the dbh all rows are being returned (without the `NVL` hack), but null columns have bytes added to them from previous rows, and not in any pattern that is obvious to me. When I leave the locale settings off of the connection string and set `LongTruncOk`, rows with null columns are selected correctly but rows with utf characters break.

So if you don't have a charset issue perhaps just `LongTruncOk` would work for you. For my purposes I have had to continue using the `NVL` workaround for nulls and specify the locales for characters.

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_2.html#nulls) - section NULL in Perl. It seems that with this driver there is no simple way to handle this problem.